# Non Cohen-Macaulay rings of dimension 2

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, graded-rings, cohen-macaulay

I am working in the context of Noetherian commutative rings with unit. It is well-known that for a field $K$, the ring $R=K[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ is a 2-dimensional standard graded $K$-algebra which not Cohen-Macaulay at its homogeneous maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4)$. In fact, one can show that $H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)$ is supported only in degree 1 as a graded module over $R$.

I am searching for additional examples of non Cohen-Macaulay rings of dimension 2. In particular, I would like examples of a reduced, (standard) graded $K$-algebra $R$ of dimension 2 with homogeneous maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that:

- $H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)$ is supported in degree $0$ and at least one other degree, and
- the degree $0$ part is $[H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)]_0=K$, the residue field.

If $R$ is a domain, then $H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)$ is finite length and so will be supported in finitely many graded degrees -- this would be the case of most interest to me. Furthermore, I would prefer the example to be independent of the characteristic of $K$, but I primarily care about the case where the characteristic of $K$ is prime. I have already searched [the example repository DaRT](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/) and could not find an example of behavior like this.

Comment: $\mathbb Z+x\mathbb Q[x]$ is at least 2 dimensional and not C-M, but I guess you have checked that it fails one of your bullet points, huh? I am not familiar with those conditions.  If you find an example, I would like to see it!

Comment: @rschwieb - I think this example is not a $K$-algebra for any field $K$... My suspicion is that for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}=p\mathbb{Z} + x\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of this ring, that $H^1_\mathfrak{m}$ will be infinite length (the domain implies $H^1$ has finite length part relies on $K$-algebra I think), but I have not worked it out.

Comment: @rschwieb To follow up, it looks like the reference I was thinking for domain implies finite length $H^1$ requires the ring to be the image of a Gorenstein domain to utilize local duality. I have no idea how to check whether $\mathbb{Z}+x\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has such a ring mapping onto it. The reference is Anurag K. Singh and Uli Walther - A connectedness result in positive characteristic - Proposition 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this post is over a year old, so maybe you've already found all the examples you need. But what about something like the Segre product of a hypersurface and a polynomial ring
$$R=\frac{k[a,b]}{(a^3+b^3)} \# k[c,d].$$

This is not reduced if $k$ has characteristic 3, but is in all other characteristics.

<del>Then $\dim\left(\frac{k[a,b]}{(a^3+b^3)} \# k[c,d] \right) = 2$, and by the  Künneth formula due to Goto-Watanable, $H^1_{\mathfrak{m}_R}(R) = H^1_{(a,b)}\left(\frac{k[a,b]}{(a^3+b^3)}\right) \# k[c,d]$.</del>

I think I was actually missing some hypotheses, so we can't use the Künneth formula after all, as $\frac{k[a,b]}{(a^3+b^3)}$ is not normal. Leaving this comment in case it can be salvaged!

I think $H^1_{(a,b)}\left(\frac{k[a,b]}{(a^3+b^3)}\right)$ should have something nonzero in degree 0. Let $S=k[a,b]/(a^3+b^3)$. The ideal $\sqrt{(a)}$ in $S$ is $(a,b)$, so we could construct a Cech complex
$$ 0 \to S \to S_a \to 0.$$ Then $\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{b^2}{a}$ are elements in $S_a$ of degree 0 and 1 respectively; I claim they are nonzero elements of $H^1_{(a,b)}(S)$.

To prove that $\frac{b}{a}$ is not in $S$, give $S$ a $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ grading where $\deg(a)=(1,0)$ and $\deg(b)=(0,1)$. Then $a^3+b^3$ is homogeneous of degree $(0,0)$. However, $\frac{b}{a}$ is of $\mathbb{Z}^3 \times \mathbb{Z}^3$ degree $(2,1)$ and standard degree $0$.  Similarly, $\frac{b^2}{a}$ is of degree $(2,2)$. In $S$, the only elements of standard degree 0 are field elements, which have $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ degree $(0,0)$.

Therefore we have nonzero elements $H^1_{(a,b)}\left(\frac{k[a,b]}{a^2+b^2}\right)$ in degree 0 and 1, and so nonzero elements in $H^1_{\mathfrak{m}_R}(R)$ of degree 0 and 1.

Comment: $a$ is a nonzerodivisor on $S$ and if $b=as$, $s\in S$, then $b^3=a^3s^3$, so $a^3(s^3+1)=0$. It follows that $s^3+1=0$, so $s$ is invertible, that is, $s\in k^\times$. This implies that a homogeneous element of degree one, $b-as$, belongs to an ideal generated by a homogeneous element of degree 3, $a^3+b^3$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I found many examples in the context of monomial ideals if I allow myself to drop the requirement that the example be reduced.

For example, if $S=K[x,y,z,w]/(xyz,xw,yw,zw)$, then $S$ is dimension $2$ and depth $1$, so is not Cohen-Macaulay, and further if $\mathfrak{m}$ is the homogeneous maximal ideal of $S$ we have $H^1_\mathfrak{m}(S)=K$ is concentrated in degree $0$.

By results of Takayama in the paper "Combinatorial characterizations of generalized Cohen-Macaulay monomial ideals," if we adjust to the ring $R=K[x,y,z,w]/(xyz,x^2w^2,y^2w^2,z^2w^2)$, then $H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)$ will be supported in degree 0 with $[H^1_\mathfrak{m}(R)]_0=K$ and additional degrees, and still be dimension $2$ and depth $1$.

Many examples can be produced this way by adjusting Stanley-Reisner ideals related to simplicial complexes of dimension $1$ which are disconnected.